# Assign jquery extend result to this

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm doing the following (example):

```
function NameConfig(cfg) {
    var config = $.extend({
        name: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }, cfg);
}
```

Now to assign this config to "this" I do this one:

```
for (var key in config)
    this[key] = config[key];
```

Can I do it in a better way?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The loop in your second code sample will just be a clone of `config`, but what is `this` referring to?

Comment: `this` should be referring to `NameConfig` or am I wrong?

Comment: Are you doing a `new NameConfig` somewhere. In that case, it will refer to the `NameConfig` instance. Else it won't refer to anything is not explicitly set

Comment: yeah sorry i do a `new NameConfig` somehwere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you do a `new NameConfig` somewhere (for `this` to be set).

Now I think jQuery's `extend` method does exactly what you want to do. Quoting the documentation, it says:

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

So you can simply do

```
function NameConfig(cfg) {
    var config = $.extend(this, {
        name: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }, cfg);
}
```

And it will work as expected.

That being said, I wouldn't recommend writing directly into `this` as you can easily have some namespacing issues.
Maybe just adding a `config` property on `this` would do the trick (depending on your use case of course)

`this.config = $.extend(/*...*/)`